# Errors while booting custom android image for tegra platform

Tags: android, boot, android-source, tegra

### Errors while booting custom android image for tegra platform

I am trying to install a custom android image on to tegra 250 board.

For this I have downloaded android sources from nv-tegra.nvidia.com site and build a custom image.

Now I am trying to flash our custom image using the flash utility provided by nvidia.

When I just flash system.img and keep the kernel same as provided by nvidia, I am getting following errors during boot. In this case system is in a hang state and screen is blank.

### Logcat output:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 1805): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1805): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1805): creating instr width table
D/AndroidRuntime( 1805): --- registering native functions ---
I/SamplingProfilerIntegration( 1805): Profiler is disabled.
I/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloading classes...

E/Zygote  ( 1805): setreuid() failed. errno: 30

D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 821 objects / 47496 bytes in 1ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 219 objects / 13600 bytes in 1ms
I/bluetooth_ScoSocket.cpp( 1805): Entry name = MY-CAR ScoTypes = 0x7f
I/bluetooth_ScoSocket.cpp( 1805): Entry name = Motorola HF850 ScoTypes = 0x7
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 253 objects / 14360 bytes in 1ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 466 objects / 28880 bytes in 2ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2090 objects / 108352 bytes in 3ms

W/MediaProfiles( 1805): could not find media config xml file

D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 264 objects / 15104 bytes in 3ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5081 objects / 225952 bytes in 5ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11277 objects / 382552 bytes in 7ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9789 objects / 461648 bytes in 8ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8711 objects / 423216 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7696 objects / 460744 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7196 objects / 460080 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8264 objects / 457520 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6875 objects / 455480 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1347 objects / 89480 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 598 objects / 29376 bytes in 9ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 449 objects / 25120 bytes in 9ms
D/        ( 1804): 2s elapsed in InitFifo; is daemon started?
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 306 objects / 35040 bytes in 13ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 279 objects / 19072 bytes in 13ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 341 objects / 18552 bytes in 13ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 449 objects / 28312 bytes in 13ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 527 objects / 52888 bytes in 15ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 623 objects / 34000 bytes in 15ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 861 objects / 46888 bytes in 15ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1747 objects / 85496 bytes in 15ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 447 objects / 29456 bytes in 16ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 315 objects / 20128 bytes in 16ms
I/Zygote  ( 1805): ...preloaded 1265 classes in 1373ms.
E/Zygote  ( 1805): setreuid() failed. errno: 30
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 104 objects / 14208 bytes in 16ms
I/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloading resources...
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 312 objects / 15568 bytes in 16ms
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801e8 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_confirm_gray.9.png) that varies with configuration!!

W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ec (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801ed (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_bar_left_end_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f1 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_confirm_gray.9.png) that varies with configuration!
!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f5 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_normal.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801f6 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_bar_right_end_pressed.9.png) that varies with configuration!!
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 392 objects / 23912 bytes in 16ms
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x10801fb (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_left_confirm_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080200 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_left_normal.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080201 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_left_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080203 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_right_confirm_gray.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080209 (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_right_normal.png) that varies with configuration!!
W/Zygote  ( 1805): Preloaded drawable resource #0x108020a (res/drawable-mdpi/jog_tab_right_pressed.png) that varies with configuration!!
I/Zygote  ( 1805): ...preloaded 61 resources in 114ms.
I/Zygote  ( 1805): ...preloaded 15 resources in 3ms.
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 331 objects / 19968 bytes in 16ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 111 objects / 4392 bytes in 16ms
D/dalvikvm( 1805): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 16ms
I/dalvikvm( 1805): System server process 1808 has been created
I/Zygote  ( 1805): Accepting command socket connections
E/BatteryService( 1808): usbOnlinePath not found
I/sysproc ( 1808): Entered system_init()
I/sysproc ( 1808): ServiceManager: 0x11e058
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1808): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1808): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
```

---

When I replace the kernel image (boot.img) along with system.img, I am getting following errors. System just keeps rebooting in this case.

### Logcat output:

```
- waiting for device -
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
I/DEBUG   (  956): debuggerd: May 21 2011 00:17:27
E/dhcpcd  (  967): fopen `/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd.conf': Permission denied
E/logwrapper(  966): Usage: logwrapper [-x] BINARY [ARGS ...]
E/logwrapper(  966):
E/logwrapper(  966): Forks and executes BINARY ARGS, redirecting stdout and stderr to
E/logwrapper(  966): the Android logging system. Tag is set to BINARY, priority is
E/logwrapper(  966): always LOG_INFO.
E/logwrapper(  966):
E/logwrapper(  966): -x: Causes logwrapper to SIGSEGV when BINARY terminates
E/logwrapper(  966):     fault address is set to the status of wait()
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/Vold    (  954): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
E/Vold    (  954): Error reading configuration (No such file or directory)... continuing anyways
D/AndroidRuntime(  978):
D/AndroidRuntime(  978): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  978): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm(  978): creating instr width table
D/dalvikvm(  978): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/core.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  978): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/ext.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  978): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  978): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/android.policy.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  978): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/services.jar'
D/dalvikvm(  978): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.nvidia.graphics.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  978): ERROR: no valid entries found in bootclasspath '/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.ja
r:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/com.nvidia.graphics.jar'
W/dalvikvm(  978): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
E/AndroidRuntime(  978): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
E/logwrapper( 1018): Usage: logwrapper [-x] BINARY [ARGS ...]
E/logwrapper( 1018):
E/logwrapper( 1018): Forks and executes BINARY ARGS, redirecting stdout and stderr to
E/logwrapper( 1018): the Android logging system. Tag is set to BINARY, priority is
E/logwrapper( 1018): always LOG_INFO.
E/logwrapper( 1018):
E/logwrapper( 1018): -x: Causes logwrapper to SIGSEGV when BINARY terminates
E/logwrapper( 1018):     fault address is set to the status of wait()
D/AndroidRuntime( 1013):
D/AndroidRuntime( 1013): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1013): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1013): creating instr width table
D/dalvikvm( 1013): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/core.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1013): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/ext.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1013): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1013): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/android.policy.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1013): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/services.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1013): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.nvidia.graphics.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 1013): ERROR: no valid entries found in bootclasspath '/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.ja
r:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/com.nvidia.graphics.jar'
W/dalvikvm( 1013): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 1013): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
D/AndroidRuntime( 1030):
D/AndroidRuntime( 1030): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1030): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1030): creating instr width table
D/dalvikvm( 1030): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/core.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1030): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/ext.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1030): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1030): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/android.policy.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1030): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/services.jar'
D/dalvikvm( 1030): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.nvidia.graphics.jar'
E/dalvikvm( 1030): ERROR: no valid entries found in bootclasspath '/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.ja
r:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/com.nvidia.graphics.jar'
W/dalvikvm( 1030): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
E/logwrapper( 1039): Usage: logwrapper [-x] BINARY [ARGS ...]
E/logwrapper( 1039):
E/logwrapper( 1039): Forks and executes BINARY ARGS, redirecting stdout and stderr to
E/logwrapper( 1039): the Android logging system. Tag is set to BINARY, priority is
E/logwrapper( 1039): always LOG_INFO.
E/logwrapper( 1039):
E/logwrapper( 1039): -x: Causes logwrapper to SIGSEGV when BINARY terminates
E/logwrapper( 1039):     fault address is set to the status of wait()
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Android source on http://nv-tegra.nvidia.com look strange, most android projects very old, 
probably their android source is also incomplete. I see only sample device and vendor projects.
Better use aosp or cyanogenmod tegra based device configs as start for your board.